# Determine the equation of a parabola with roots $2 + \sqrt {3}$ and $2 - \sqrt {3}$, and passing through the point $(2,5)$

Tags: quadratics

My attempt:

$$f(x) = a(x - r)(x - s)$$
$$f(x) = a(x-(2 + \sqrt {3}))(x-(2- \sqrt {3}))$$

From here, I'm stuck. I can't remember where to go from this point and need some help.

Comment: What is $f(2)$ and what should it be?

Comment: Hint: $$\text{Since }(2,5)\text{ belongs to the parabola it follows } f(2)=5$$

Comment: $f(2)=5$, so $a=\frac{5}{(2-(2+\sqrt{3}))(2-(2-\sqrt{3}))}$

Comment: You have $2+\sqrt 2$ in the title, but $2+\sqrt 3$ in the body.

Comment: Also, note that you can simplify $(x-(2+\sqrt{3}))(x-(2-\sqrt{3}))$ into a rational polynomial and it's probably worth expanding that out before you go further.

Answer (score 1):

You've used several pieces of your information, but not all. You haven't used the fact that it passes through $(2,5)$, i.e. that $f(2) = 5$. So you should plug in $2$ and $5$ and then solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

The vertex must lie on the axis of symmetry. This is equal to the mean of the $x$-coordinates of the roots, or $x = \frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt3 + 2-\sqrt3 \right) = 2$.

Therefore we can write the equation of the parabola in vertex form: $y = a(x-2)^2 + b$. Use the fact that it passes through $(2,5)$, and $(0, 2+\sqrt{3})$ to form a system in two equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a(2 - 2)^2 + b = 5  \\
a(2 + \sqrt3 - 2)^2 + b=0\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Now the equation of the parabola is obvious.